# Facebook.php and facebookapi_php5 documentation

Tags: php, facebook

Wher can I find a good documentation on these two PHP files and a more detail & indepth use of each function?

Facebook documentation is... not informatitve enough. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Facebook is always changing their API, the documentation is inevitably lacking and/or out of date. If you are looking up viral information, you going to find a lot of pages that say they have been deprecated.

My most used pages are:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBML
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS

You can play around with the API here:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?api

But in the end, just about everything in those files gets passed through the post_request function in the facebook_php5_restlib file. That's where the curl function is for "posting" to Facebook. You can always capture what's going on in that function.

Comment: the biggest problem is that, inside those functions, especially the PHP lib, there is nothing about the parameter type, return type. No sample and has to test around.  Even the JS API has the same problem.  even it says Object type, it doesn't tell much about what kind of object is expected.. OMG....

Comment: Most of the Facebook API/function calls have optional parameters, so the only object type expected is a name/value pairing object. I believe they now use json across the board to submit the name/value pairs.

To generalize, you submit a function name and name/value pairs to use as parameters.

Comment: The wiki links mentioned in the answer lead nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain.

facebookapi_php5 is mainly each API method.
facebook is mainly for session/auth.

The best place I've found so far is the developer forums, but it is mainly questions without answers.