# Documentation of facebook's PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook.php and facebookapi_php5 documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337251/facebook-php-and-facebookapi-php5-documentation)

Where can I see a documentation of all the methods in facebook's PHP sdk, such as what each method does, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is usually a documentation near every method... 
It's not that good, but there isn't anything better.

Comment: bad example  : 

  /**
   * Make an API call.
   *
   * @return mixed The decoded response
   */
  public function api(/* polymorphic */) {

Comment: /* polymorphic */ wtf. and how to know which args are correct ?